# QTY at 0 doesn't change product to Out of Stock

Tags: stock, out-of-stock

**UPDATE: I figured out that the issue is that while this script updates the item in the `cataloginventory_stock_item` table, it fails to update it in the `cataloginventory_stock_status` table. Added an answer for how to fix this.**

The following script is being used to update the inventory levels of items in my store:

```
<?

 define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
 require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';

 umask(0);
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
 $count = 0;

 $file = fopen(MAGENTO . '/var/import/updateStockLevels.csv', 'r');
 while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) { 

 if ($count == 0) {
 foreach ($line as $key=>$value) {
 $cols[$value] = $key;
 } 
 } 

 $count++;

 if ($count == 1) continue;

 #Convert the lines to cols 
 if ($count > 0) { 
 foreach($cols as $col=>$value) {
 unset(${$col});
 ${$col} = $line[$value];
 } 
 }

 // Check if SKU exists
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku); 

 if ( $product ) {

 $productId = $product->getId();
 $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
 $stockItemId = $stockItem->getId();
 $stock = array();

 if (!$stockItemId) {
 $stockItem->setData('product_id', $product->getId());
 $stockItem->setData('stock_id', 1); 
 } else {
 $stock = $stockItem->getData();
 }

 foreach($cols as $col=>$value) {
 $stock[$col] = $line[$value];
 } 

 foreach($stock as $field => $value) {
 $stockItem->setData($field, $value?$value:0);
 }



 $stockItem->save();

 unset($stockItem);
 unset($product);
 }

 echo "<br />Stock updated $sku";

 }
 fclose($file);

?>
```

This script works great and all qty levels are updated accurately. The issue is with the in stock check.

If I go to an item page on the frontend that has qty zero after running the script, it shows it as `In Stock`. However, when I go to check that item in the backend, the `Inventory->Stock Availability` field correctly shows as `Out of Stock`, and the database itself has the correct value.

If I go to the product page in the admin, and click to save the product (since it already shows it correctly being out of stock in the availability field), its fixes the problem. The frontend will now show it properly as out of stock.

Since `qty` set to `0` and `is_in_stock` set to `false (0)` is not enough to mark it properly as `Out of Stock` on the frontend, I assume that there must be some field that I am not properly updating in my script, that is only updated properly when I save the item from the admin backend. However I don't know what field(s) I could be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirmed that the issue was in fact that some fields were not being updated that needed to be. These fields ended up being `qty` and `stock_status` in the table `cataloginventory_stock_status`. I found a couple ways to fix this. You can update each item in the script using the `assign` function that the `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Status` has. Simply place it in the `if ( $product )` loop.

The other way is to use the `rebuild` function that the `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Status` has. You call this outside the `if` loop and it will rebuild all the stock statuses on the site based on their newly updated `qty`. This is the method I used, and my edit was simply adding this function call after the `if` loop, right after the `fclose` line.

```
fclose($handle);

$stockStatus = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_status')->rebuild($website_Id);
```

It increases the script run time by about 30-40%, but the script is still quite quick and now it works fully.